# How to check if a string is a letter(a-z or A-Z) in c

Tags: c, char, uppercase, lowercase, ctype

I am getting user input, and I want to determine if the user has entered a letter , an integer, or an operator. I can successfully determine if it is an integer using sscanf, but I am stumped on how to determine if it is a letter.

By letter, I mean: A-Z, a-z.

```
int main(){
    char buffer[20];
    int integer; 
    printf("Enter expression: ");
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL){
        char *p = strchr(buffer, '\n'); //take care of the new line from fgets
        if (p) *p = 0;

        //Buffer will either be a integer, an operator, or a variable (letter).
        //I would like a way to check if it is a letter
        //I am aware of isalpha() but that requires a char and buffer is a string

         //Here is how I am checking if it is an integer
         if (sscanf(buffer, "%d", &integer) != 0){
             printf("Got an integer\n");
         }
         else if (check if letter)
             // need help figuring this out
         } 
         else{
             // must be an operator
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW: If you entered only spaces, `(sscanf(" ", "%d", &integer)` would yield -1 and _pass_ your "Got an integer\n" test.  Recommend in the future use _affirmative_ `sscanf()` comparison tests such as `sscanf(buffer, "%d", &integer) == 1` for `sscanf(..., "%d",...)` may be expected to return 0, 1 or EOF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `isalpha()` and `isdigit()` standard functions. Just include `<ctype.h>`.

```
     if (isdigit(integer)) != 0){
         printf("Got an integer\n");
     }
     else if (isalpha(integer))
         printf"Got a char\n"); 
     } 
     else{
         // must be an operator 
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but how do change buffer to an integer?

Comment: just use the first character of the buffer and cast it to `int`.

Answer (score 7):

To find out if the input is *a letter* or *a digit*:

- `int isalpha ( int c );` function to verify whether `c` is an *alphabetic letter*.
- `int isalnum ( int c );` function to verify whether `c` is either a *decimal digit* or an *uppercase or lowercase letter*.
- `int isdigit ( int c );` function to verify whether `c` is a *decimal digit character*.

To find out if the letter is *uppercase* or *lowercase*:

- `int islower ( int c );` to checks whether `c` is *a lowercase letter*: **a-z**
- `int isupper ( int c );` to checks whether `c` is *a uppercase letter*: **A-Z**

Put them into `if` statements which do something (`true` or `false`), depending on the result.

**PS** You can find out more about  standard library here: [Character handling functions: ctype.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/)