# Is there any inbuilt function in C to check for special characters (like space and tab) just like isdigit() function

Tags: c

Wanted to know if there is any inbuilt function in C to check for special characters like space, tab just like the `isdigit()` function?

Comment: There's a [whole set of isxxxxx character functions in the C library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalnum) if you take the time to look. If what you want isn't there, then write one that does what you want. You're *probably* interested in `isspace`.

Comment: Re your question tags: I recommend reading [Understanding the Differences Between C#, C++, and C](https://csharp-station.com/understanding-the-differences-between-c-c-and-c/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using C isdigit for error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528628/using-c-isdigit-for-error-checking)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a string is a letter(a-z or A-Z) in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896645/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-lettera-z-or-a-z-in-c)

Comment: Neither of the proposed duplicates is remotely appropriate as a duplicate.  It won't be surprising to find that there is a duplicate.  However, neither of those is the right duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up and learn the functions defined by the C11 standard in the [§7.4 Character handling `<ctype.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4) functions.

The [`isspace()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4.1.10) function looks for a fairly general set of white space characters:

```
' ', '\t', '\r', '\f', '\n', '\v'
```

The [`isblank()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4.1.3) function looks for the set you want:

```
' ', '\t'
```

To some extent, the POSIX variants are locale dependent — the POSIX specifications for [`isspace()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isspace.html) and [`isblank()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isblank.html) are less emphatic about which characters are matched, but disclaim conflict with the C standard, so in the C locale, the behaviour is as required by the C standard.